# Autoplay on USB hotswap

Tags: usb, media

I would like to use a Rpi to facilitate creating a presentation board (TV)

The simple solution would be to network connect the Rpi and have a chrome in kiosk mode (maybe a local webserver...). However... it cannot be network connected.

Is it possible to start a Rpi to read a usb stick and autoplay a specifically named file. Equally can the USB be hotswapped to then autoplay again on re-insertion?

For a cold start I think I have it figured out but a hotswap is what is troubling me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto start is definitely possible - I have just finished implementing this for a client installation. I posted my setup in response to an older question on the board about this:

raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8805/auto-login-into-lxde-and-auto-start-video-player-omxplayer/28740#28740

If you have any questions about that setup then feel free to mail me.

As for hotswapping, I would imagine that you can adapt the method that I used for a secondary part of the project. I configured swatch so that it would watch the log and when it detected a USB disconnect it would safely shut down the Pi. I think that you could adapt this so that instead of shutting down the Pi on disconnect, you could launch a video on connection.

In fact I'm fairly certain that you can do it this way. If you want any help setting that up to do this then I'd happily help, just send me a message.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply... My Pi arrived this morning and I had it booting once I got back from work. Omxplayer works fine - although I need to make the virtualTerminal black...  your solution is ok-ish but I have a much neater solution and I have 3 of the 4 ( autostart [x], stop on removal [x], play on insertion [x], default if none [] )cases working (abusing udev and mkfifo's). Ill accept this answer as at the very least it got me thinking

Comment: Care to share the details of your solution? Mine is utterly disgusting, it's a hacked together mish-mash of about 3 to 4 different tutorials and examples that I found. If you have a better one then I'm very interested in the details of it :)

Comment: Will do, still tidying up the bash but right now it is functioning as expected